# Middle characters in string not being reversed - C++ (Reinvent)

Tags: c++, string

Trying to just make a small string reverser and when reversing the characters of a string with an odd length return, only the first and last characters of the string seem to be getting swapped:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word;
    cout << "Word: ";
    cin >> word;
    if (word.length() % 2 == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (word.length()/2); i++)
        {
            swap(word[i], word[word.length() - i - 1]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (word.length()/2 - 1); i++)
        {
            swap(word[i], word[word.length() - i]);
        }
    }
    cout << word << endl;
}
```

Comment: you can reverse string by std::reverse()

Comment: I know I just wanted to manually do it for practice

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: did you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: @MORTAL The code is not fine. There is at least a buffer overflow in the `else`case.

Comment: @5gon12eder I'm trying to understand why it isn't swapping any of the characters in the middle of an odd length string

Comment: why not try it differently by starting with a new string and appending the characters from `word` from the end to the beginning? then you need only one loop.

Comment: Didn't even think about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexing logic is not correct.  Look at this.

```
swap(word[i], word[word.length() - i]);
```

The loop starts with `i == 0` sou you're trying to `swap()` characters at position `i == 0` and `word.length() - i == word.length() - 0 == word.length()` which is out-of-bounds and therefore undefined behavior.  You got that part right in the even case where you subtract 1.

Also consider what happens in the case that `word.length() == 1`. You check for

```
i < (word.length() / 2 - 1)
```

in the conditional of your `for` loop.  If `word.length() == 1`, then `word.length() / 2 == 0` and now you subtract 1 from it. This will underflow the (`unsigned`) integer, which is well-defined but gives you the most positive value so you'll loop over all kind of invalid indices.

In general, I think your case selection is needlessly complicated.  It would be easier if you used iterators.  Since you say this is an exercise for you, I won't show you the solution but you can easily find it in the web.  This question gets asked here fairly often.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word;
    cout << "Word: ";
    cin >> word;
    for (int i = 0; i < (word.length()/2); i++)
    {
        swap(word[i], word[word.length() - i - 1]);
    }
    cout << word << endl;
}
```

you do not need if/else statement.